# insert None value in python into firebird table

Tags: python, firebird

I'm trying to insert a python variable containing None value into a firebird table but it raises error (when i insert a random value it works fine ) :

```
fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError: ('Error while executing SQL statement:\n- SQLCODE: -802\n- arithmetic exception, numeric overf
low, or string truncation\n- string right truncation', -802, 335544321)
```

The python code is the following :

```
import fdb

con = fdb.connect(dsn='OFFICINE.gdb', user='SYSDBA', password='masterkey')
cur = con.cursor()

spec = None

cur.execute("update ENTETEFACT set SPECIALITE = '%s' where N_FACTURE = '04139412' " %spec)
con.commit()
```

Comment: What is the DDL of this table?

Comment: The create table, or at least the definition of the columns.

Comment: SPECIALITE column is a char(2)

Comment: Is the character set of the column `NONE`?

Comment: why you dont insert a blank char? `""`

Answer (score 0):

Why you are trying string formatting instead of passing parameters?

```
cur.execute("update ENTETEFACT set SPECIALITE = %s where N_FACTURE = '04139412' ", [spec])
```

Comment: This doesn't help me anyway